# Eleusian vs. Eleusinian (and, to a lesser extent, Elysian)

Tags: etymology, differences, suffixes

Both Eleusian and Eleusinian are used in relation to *mysteries.* I've only seen Elysian used in relation to Elysian Fields.

Given that the suffix -ian denotes "of or belonging to," I'm wondering if there is a rationale behind the use of Eleusinian. If I wanted to describe something 'of or belonging to' Eleusis, it would seem that Eleusian would be the most obvious choice.

Is Eleusinian used specifically to denote a meaning broader than originating from Eleusis? I'm wondering what (if any) the linguistic basis is for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be more precise, the English word Eleusinian can be traced to the ancient Greek Ἐλευσίς (Elefsis, `eu` is read as `f`in Greek) which becomes Ἐλευσῖνος (Elefsinos) in the genitive and provides the -in- in Eleusinian. Ἐλευσίς is a place name (Ελευσίνα, pronounced Elefsina, in modern Greek) and since the mysteries are the mysteries *of* Eleusis, in Greek the genitive is used so they are the mysteries of Ἐλευσῖνος => Eleusinian.

Eleusian is simply wrong and [Elysian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium) is completely unrelated, it comes from the ancient Greek Ἠλύσιον which is the name of a place in the underworld (Hades). It was, essentially, the nice neighborhood of Hell, the equivalent of Heaven. It has absolutely nothing to do with Eleysis or its mysteries.

Comment: +1 for discussion of Elysian (especially “the nice neighborhood of Hell”).

Comment: So informative- I'm definitely going to be looking in to "the nice neighborhood of hell" so that I can try to weave that into casual conversation...

Comment: @batpigandme yeah, it was a great place really, back in the day people were just _dying_ to get in there.

Comment: Entirely correct, but note that the town is called *Eleusis* not *Eleysis* in English: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusis.  Modern Greeks often think Ancient Greek should not affect the Roman-alphabet spelling of Greek names: it does.

Comment: @TimLymington so it is, thanks. In any case it has as much to do with Ancient Greek as Modern since the spelling is the same. Its just that the Greek `υ` is sometimes transliterated to the latin alphabet as `y`(as in _Elysian_, gr: Ἠλύσιον) and sometimes as `u` (as in _Eleusis_, gr: Ἐλευσίς) so it is hard to remember which has been chosen when.

Answer (score 6):

According to [American Heritage and Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Eleusian+Mysteries), *Eleusinian* is from Latin *Eleusīni(us)* “of Eleusis,” which is in turn from Greek *Eleusinios.* The stem change doesn't indicate any special meaning; that's simply how it appears in the source languages. (As terdon notes, it's from the genitive inflection of the name.)

*Eleusian* does not appear in dictionaries, and [very rarely](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Eleusinian%20mysteries,Eleusian%20mysteries&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) appears in English writing. It's most likely a misspelling.